# How to Use Tidyverse to Remove Select Duplicate Values Based on the Value of Another Column

Tags: r, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

Using the example data at the bottom, I'm trying to remove duplicates in the ID column, but only the duplicates where the "Year" column equals 2017.

I tried the code below, which doesn't seem to work.

```
DF <- DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(REMOVE = if_else(duplicated(ID) & Year == 2017, 1, 0))

DF <- DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(REMOVE = if_else(!unique(ID) & Year == 2017, 1, 0))
```

I'm trying to use the code to group by "ID", then use an "if_else" statement to code year 2017 within each group of duplicate ID's with a 1. I'll then remove all the 1's with the filter code below.

```
DF <- DF %>%
  filter(REMOVE == 1)
```

I'm not sure why this code isn't working. I've also tried changing the column types for ID and Year from character, numeric, etc, but this didn't help.

Help would be appreciated!

```
ID<-c(18998878,8888888,57485746,18998878,45454536,64536475,64536475,87966666,58675844,58695847,68574443,87966666)
Program<-c("A111","B488","T687","A111","G888","T444","T444","P867","R444","B323","F888","P867")
Code<-c(1222,4534,543,1222,4678,6544,6544,9898,8888,5656,6666,9898)
Year<-c(2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017)
DF<-data_frame(ID,Program,Code,Year)
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what the desired output is? I'm not sure I understand what you're looking for.

Comment: Just a general suggestion: often when you think you should use `ifelse()` you can just use the logical test you're passing to `ifelse()`. That function is for assigning other kinds of binary values to the result of a logical test, for example `male` or `female`.  If you're using  it to create a vector (or column) with 0s and 1s, you probably don't need `ifelse`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort `DF` by `ID` and `Year` then use `distinct` to keep only `Year = 2016` values

```r
library(dplyr)

ID <- c(18998878,8888888,57485746,18998878,45454536,64536475,64536475,87966666,
        58675844,58695847,68574443,87966666)
Program <- c("A111","B488","T687","A111","G888","T444","T444","P867","R444","B323","F888","P867")
Code <- c(1222,4534,543,1222,4678,6544,6544,9898,8888,5656,6666,9898)
Year <- c(2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017)
DF <- data_frame(ID,Program,Code,Year)
DF
#> # A tibble: 12 x 4
#>           ID Program  Code  Year
#>        <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1 18998878. A111    1222. 2016.
#>  2  8888888. B488    4534. 2016.
#>  3 57485746. T687     543. 2017.
#>  4 18998878. A111    1222. 2017.
#>  5 45454536. G888    4678. 2017.
#>  6 64536475. T444    6544. 2017.
#>  7 64536475. T444    6544. 2016.
#>  8 87966666. P867    9898. 2016.
#>  9 58675844. R444    8888. 2016.
#> 10 58695847. B323    5656. 2017.
#> 11 68574443. F888    6666. 2017.
#> 12 87966666. P867    9898. 2017.


DF %>% 
  arrange(ID, Year) %>% 
  distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>          ID Program  Code  Year
#>       <dbl> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  8888888. B488    4534. 2016.
#> 2 18998878. A111    1222. 2016.
#> 3 45454536. G888    4678. 2017.
#> 4 57485746. T687     543. 2017.
#> 5 58675844. R444    8888. 2016.
#> 6 58695847. B323    5656. 2017.
#> 7 64536475. T444    6544. 2016.
#> 8 68574443. F888    6666. 2017.
#> 9 87966666. P867    9898. 2016.
```

Created on 2018-03-07 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 1):

```
ID<-c(18998878,8888888,57485746,18998878,45454536,64536475,64536475,87966666,58675844,58695847,68574443,87966666)
Program<-c("A111","B488","T687","A111","G888","T444","T444","P867","R444","B323","F888","P867")
Code<-c(1222,4534,543,1222,4678,6544,6544,9898,8888,5656,6666,9898)
Year<-c(2016,2016,2017,2017,2017,2017,2016,2016,2016,2017,2017,2017)
DF<-data_frame(ID,Program,Code,Year)

filter(DF, (! duplicated(ID)) & Year == 2017)
```

This removes the second or later occurrence of any ID, provided the year is 2017. Of note there are no examples of that, so I may have misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 0):

You break it into two data frames, one with year equals 2017 and one with year does not equal 2017.

```
 DF1 <- DF %>% filter(Year==2017) 
 DF2 <- DF %>% filter(Year!=2017)
```

Then dedup on DF1 by its ID column using distinct(). Keep_all is to keep the rest values.

```
 DF3 <- DF1 %>% distinct(ID,.keep_all = T)
```

Now you can get you final result by combine DF2 and DF3 with rbind()

```
 df_all <- rbind(DF2,DF3)
```